# Alias doesn't work for aptitude search in Eshell

Tags: eshell

`alias` works very well in Eshell. I've used it like this:

```
alias sau sudo aptitude update
```

However, it doesn't work for the search command:

```
$ alias aps aptitude search 
$ aps emacs
search: You must provide at least one search term
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short:** use `alias aps 'aptitude search $*'` (quotes seem to be important).

The comment at the top of `em-alias.el` says the following.

## Creating aliases

The user interface is simple: type `alias` followed by the command name followed by the definition.  Argument references are made using `$1`, `$2`, etc., or `$*`.  For example:

```
alias ll 'ls -l $*'
```

This will cause the command `ll NEWS` to be replaced by `ls -l NEWS`.  This is then passed back to the command parser for reparsing.{Only the command text specified in the alias definition will be reparsed.  Argument references (such as `$*`) are handled using variable values, which means that the expansion will not be reparsed, but used directly.}

To delete an alias, specify its name without a definition:

```
alias ll
```

Aliases are written to disk immediately after being defined or deleted.  The filename in which they are kept is defined by the variable `eshell-aliases-file`.

Comment: Wow, that works. You also answered my other problem: delete alias. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @Constantine This is from the "Aliases" node in `eshell`'s info doc. "Aliases are commands that expand to a longer input line.  For example,
`ll' is a common alias for `ls -l', and would be defined with the
command invocation `alias ll ls -l'; with this defined, running `ll
foo' in Eshell will actually run `ls -l foo'." - so why does this definition of `ll` work?

Comment: @Pradhan: Yes, I read the info docs too. As far as I can tell, after running `alias ll ls -l` `ll foo` runs `ls -l`, **not** `ls -l foo`, i.e. the argument is ignored. I am pretty sure this is a documentation bug. (Note that [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Built_002dins) of the manual uses the syntax described in the comment I quoted (look for "`sudo`").)